# How to Localize Xamarin Android DatePickerDialog

Tags: xamarin, localization, xamarin.android, android-resources

I have a datePickerDialog to show and it must be localized. 
What is the easiest way to do it?
Also I am doing the app to support the language that is not supported by android system yet.

I am ready to create each resource file for strings for translated values but is it possible to achieve this only buy adding resource files?

Maybe adding string values with keys that DatePickerDialog refers at runTime by current culture so it will take my localized values instead of default

Comment: You could read this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32989147/how-does-android-handle-unsupported-languages